# DefaultSharedPreferences settings for the entire application in a separate class

Tags: java, android

tell me - I want to make reading DefaultSharedPreferences settings in a separate class. and already with other Activity read data from it (in any Activity data is read but want to implement it by a separate class that does not read them every once in each Activity).
Code - Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Test t = new Test();

    String z = t.getAa();
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 }
```

Code - Test.java

```
public class Test extends PreferenceActivity {

private String aa;
private String EdittextListPreferenceFont;

public String getAa() {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    EdittextListPreferenceFont = prefs.getString("edittext_font",
            getString(R.string.font_default));
            aa = EdittextListPreferenceFont;
    return aa;
}

}
```

LogCat eclipse

```
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.invasion/com.game.invasion.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: This should be called after super.onCreate.
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: This should be called after super.onCreate.
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.requirePreferenceManager(PreferenceActivity.java:212)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:260)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at com.game.invasion.Test.getAa(Test.java:19)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at com.game.invasion.Main.onCreate(Main.java:45)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-29 19:16:13.016: E/AndroidRuntime(5804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
```

I will be grateful for the help or a link where to read about it.
PS - sorry, google translate

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure, what you want to achieve.

However, a PreferenceActivity is a class to implement UI to interact with the preferences. Here is a description: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Especially do not use a constructor to create one, but start is like any other activity using an intent.

If you just need to access the stored shared preference values you do not need to subclass any special class:

```
public class PreferenceProxy {

    private final SharedPreferences prefs;

    public PreferenceProxy(final Context ctx) {
       this. prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    }

   public String getAa() {
       prefs.getString("edittext_font", null); // or any other default value, I did not understand your code snippet
    }
```

}

However, I doubt that the proxy is worth the effort. I recommend to create an interface to define the keys, like "edittext_font". This reduces the risk for typos in the keys. Additionally you may want to have a single point to get the preferences from, e.g. your application object or a static method in your main activity which accepts a Context (like the constructor in the example). But do not implement a method for every preference unless you gain something from it because of complex default-value management, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you. is working. I downloaded the file then what settings instead of the settings. your code helped me.